# Passing SED replace arguments within a BASH variable

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to pass a variable with spaces in it to sed using BASH, and in the prompt, it works fine:

```
$ tmp=/folder1/This Folder Here/randomfile.abc
$ echo "$tmp" | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g'
/folder1/This\ Folder\ Here/randomfile.abc
```

But as soon as I pass it to a variable, sed no longer replaces the space with a backslash:

```
$ tmp=/folder1/This Folder Here/randomfile.abc
$ location=`echo "$tmp" | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g'`
$ echo $location
/folder1/This Folder Here/randomfile.abc
```

I'm hoping a second pair of eyes can pick up on something that I'm not.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this sed?

Comment: As per the first example, I want to add a backslash to all spaces within the variable, so 'This Folder Here', would be 'This\ Folder\ Here'.

Comment: Yes that I can see but why do you want to escape every space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a couple of pairs of backslashes:

```
sed -e 's/ /\\\\ /g'
```

---

You seem to want to quote the input so as to use it as shell input.  There is no need to use `sed`.  You could use `printf`:

```
$ foo="a string with spaces"
$ printf "%q" "$foo"
a\ string\ with\ spaces
```

Comment: That did it! I'd vote up if I had the reputation. Thanks devnull.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use more quoting.

```
tmp="/folder1/This Folder Here/randomfile.abc"
location="$(echo "$tmp" | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g')"
echo "$location"
```

There's also a pure `bash` solution to insert the backslashes:

```
tmp="/folder1/This Folder Here/randomfile.abc"
echo "${tmp// /\\ }"
```

Answer (score 3):

The quotes are being evaluated by bash during the assignment. You can get around this by quoting:

```
location="$(echo "$tmp" | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g')"
```

or devnull's answer (double the quotes)

Or switch to zsh to make things like this easier

```
% echo $tmp
/folder1/This Folder Here/randomfile.abc
% echo ${(q)tmp}
/folder1/This\ Folder\ Here/randomfile.abc
```

Comment: This also works, I derped by not using '"$('. Thanks for the update!